# Mask certain string attributes in Java during logging?

Tags: java, logging, masking

Is there a way I can mask certain string variables of a class like password, etc which will prevent during logging? Like overriding `toString()` method in such way it does not print in logs.

For instance, we have a class Employee with following fields:

```
public class Employee {
    private String username;
    **private String password; //mask this field**
    private String city;
}
```

During logging like

**LOGGER.INFO("printing object:"+employee);**

Here in logging, I'm trying to print the whole object, Employee here and my requirement is it **does not print out masked field, password at all** and whereas logging of rest of the fields are fine.

Comment: Just exclude it from `toString`?

Comment: Override the `toString()` method and print whatever you need...

Comment: Hash the password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First obvious option is to override toString(), example:

```
public class Employee {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String city;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "username=" + username + " city=" + city;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Employee().toString());
    }
}
```

You can also replace password string from logging, for example

```
 String maskedPassword = s.replaceAll("password=[^&]*", "password=***");
```

In you use jersey you can add [logging filter](http://howtodoinjava.com/jersey/jersey-custom-logging-request-and-response-entities-using-filter/) with such replacement.

Answer (score 2):

Create a class called MaskedString that is basically just a replacement for String but has a toString method that doesn't output the actual password:

```
public class MaskedString(){
    private String maskedString;

    MaskedString(){
        maskedString = "";
    }

    MaskedString(String string){
        maskedString = string;
    }

    public String getActualString(){
        return maskedString;
    }

    public String setString(String string){
        maskedString = string;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Not the actual string!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **lombok**,  try the exclude option for ToString.

```
@Data
@ToString(exclude = {"password"})
public class Employee {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String city;
}
```